# Datatables.responsive.js crashes when Datatable has no rows

Tags: responsive-design, datatables, datatables-1.10

As per title, I have a [Datatable](http://datatables.net/), that loads data using the ajax options. This works fine.

When I add the [responsive extension](http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) Version 1.01, it works as expected when I resize the browser EXCEPT when my datatable has no rows.

datatable.responsive.js crashes at line 561:

```
var clone = dt.row( idx ).node().cloneNode( true );
```

with error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'dt.row(...).node()' is null or not an object

I am simply adding the line:

```
responsive: true,
```

to my Datatable defintion as follows:

```js
$('#tableName').dataTable({
        processing: true,
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        serverSide: true,
        responsive: true,
        columns: [
            { name: "ID" },
            { name: "ColumnName1" },

            ...more columns
        ],
        ajax: "MyURL"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed as part of this [release](https://github.com/DataTables/Responsive/commit/b3ee059a61646ee2b985c85aba3de2e0fb896b14)